# MVVM Subclass property binding

Tags: c#, mvvm

I have issue binding class chain my listView won't refresh data: here

> simplified code:

```
  private ObservableCollection<NewPosition> _ListPosition;
      public ObservableCollection<NewPosition> ListPosition
    {
                        get { return _ListPosition; }
                       set
                        {

                           _ListPosition = value;
                           OnPropertyChanged("ListPosition");

                        }
                    }

       public class NewPosition
               { 
              public int ID { get; set; }
               public PosStatus Status { get; set; }
                public Trade buyTrade { get; set; }
               public Trade SellTrade { get; set; }

             }

       public class Trade 
      {
                  public double DealPrice {get ; set}

      }
```

> now the view

```
<ListView Grid.Row="1" Background="#FF232426" ItemsSource="{Binding 
 assetsPointCollection.ListPosition}"
     Foreground="#FFF2F3F7" Margin="0,10" FontSize="10" >
     <ListView.View>
         <GridView> 
<GridViewColumn  Header="Price" Width="80" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding buyTrade.DealPrice}" />
     <GridViewColumn  Header="SellPrice" Width="80"
     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SellTrade.DealPrice}" />  
                             </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
               </Grid>
```

So whenn i first set dealprice and add it to collection it does the job and listview show value;

```
 NewPosition thisPos = new NewPosition();
   var trade = new Trade()
                {                   
                    DealPrice = 1000,
                 }
  thisPos.buyTrade = trade;
   ListPosition.Add(thisPos);
```

the problem is when i want later set NewPosition.Selltrade.Dealprice
the GUI will no show change (it work in console)

```
 pos.SellTrade = new Trade{DealPrice = 1200};
```

so what is the "elegante manner to implement such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because NewPosition and Trade does not implement [INotifyProperyChange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged), like your View Model does. The windowing system does not compare the object values, and relies on something telling it a property has changed.

For the change to be picked up, you would have to remove, and add your NewPosition again, since the [ObservableCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1) does notify any changes.

You could look at [MvvmLite](http://www.mvvmlight.net) for a simple framework to help you.

Example using ObservableObject from MvvmLite, which implements INotifyPropertyChanged for you:

```
public class NewPosition : ObservableObject
{ 
    private int _id;
    public int ID {
        get => _id;
        set => Set(ref _id, value); 
    }

    private PosStatus _status;
    public PosStatus Status {
        get => _status;
        set => Set(ref _status, value);
    }

    private Trade _buyTrade;
    public Trade buyTrade { 
        get => _buyTrade;
        set => Set(ref _buyTrade, value);
    }

    private Trade _sellTrade;
    public Trade SellTrade { 
        get => _sellTrade;
        set => Set(ref _sellTrade, value);
    }
}

public class Trade : ObservableObject
{
    private double _dealPrice;
    public double DealPrice {
        get => _dealPrice;
        set => Set(ref _dealPrice, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: is this the only way to do this? it seem strange way to implement it no?

Comment: Or just implement INPC on `NewPosition`, but *something* needs to raise that event

Comment: or maybee it have way to implement INotifyProperyChange in trade and NewPosition honestly i tried but no result

Comment: i think i did something wrong trying implement it if you have a sample for Trade and newPosition i take it ;)

Comment: ok found it i did it only for Trade nor for Newposition but its lot of writing need to refactor the notify methode

Comment: @Zwan I added an example using MvvmLite toolkit. Other MVVM libraries would have a similar implementation.